# JavaScript undefined in IE 7 but works in IE 8

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get first character from the `clsName` i.e. '+' or '-' in variable `n`.
This works in IE 8 but in IE 7 I get 'undefined'.
Please let me know how do I fix it.

```
var clsName = $(this).attr("class");
var n = $('.'+clsName).text()[0];
alert(n);
```

Comment: can you knock up an example in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Why do you need a `[0]` here?

Comment: yes class name start with sign. CharAt works fine. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String[index]` is not supported in IE7-. Use [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) instead:

```
var n = $('.'+clsName).text().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole code inside `$(document).ready();`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clsName = $(this).attr("class");
    var n = $('.'+clsName).text()[0];
    alert(n);
});
```